# How to fill a form field of type fieldset with values from an array

Tags: forms

How can I fill a formfield type fieldset with more than one markup value from an array?

```
foreach ($drugis_postgis_connection->tableNames() as $table) {
    $form['tables'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Tables'),
      '#markup' => $table, 
      '#collapsible' => TRUE, // Added
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,  // Added
  ];
```

I don't need more fields i want to markup all values from the array in the field. Actually there is only one value, from the array displayed.

---

Sorry if my question is not clear, i want something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you overwrite `$form['tables']` on each iteration, you're only going to end up with one `tables` on the form. Each element on the `$form` needs to have a unique name. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($drugis_postgis_connection->tableNames() as $key => $table) {

  $form['table' . $key] = [
    /** ... **/
  ];

}
```

If you want only one fieldset, then trying something like this:

```
$tables = $drugis_postgis_connection->tableNames();
$form['tables'] = [
  /** ... **/
  '#markup' => implode('', $tables),
  /** ... **/
];
```

Comment: This works fine, but it created vor every value an own block, i want to list all tables in one form???

Comment: I'm assuming you mean one fieldset. If that's the case, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question doesn't work for two reasons.

- The `foreach` loop is overriding `$form['tables']` each time, with the effect that `$form['tables']['#markup']` contains only the last table name found from `$drugis_postgis_connection->tableNames()`
- A *fieldset* element doesn't use `#markup`

You need to use code similar to the following one.

```php
$tables = $drugis_postgis_connection->tableNames();

$form['tables'] = [
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => $this->t('Tables'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
];

$form['tables']['list'] = [
  '#markup' => implode(',', $tables),
];
```

I assume `$drugis_postgis_connection->tableNames()` returns an array of strings; otherwise, `implode(',', $tables)` needs to be changed.